# Getting error when trying to debug on chromes emulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to run a sample app by using cordovas camera plugin and I got an error, when trying to debug on chromes emulator

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                      
(http://localhost:8000/android/www/css/images/ajax-loader.gif)
```

Comment: Make sure that file is in `android/www/css/images/ajax-loader.gif`

Answer (score 1):

You are debuging your application in chrome emulator. But you are using the `ajax-loader.gif` placed in `platforms/andoroid/www/css/images` change the location of the loader to www folder in the root folder.
`css/images/ajax-loader.gif`.

In chrome emulator, the files in www folder in the root of project is taken.

Change the location of loader and check whether the problem is solved or not

Answer (score 1):

The correct path is `css/images/ajax-loader.gif`